# adding an *owner attribute to an inventory class

Tags: c++, class

I'm stuck on a problem that might be pretty basic and probably a bit too object-oriented..
The idea was to give each object of the class "Inventory" an attribute which points to an at runtime existing object of the class "person", otherwise it would point to a nullptr or something equivalent;
So that each "Inventory" can be potentially linked to a specific "Person".

Rn it gives me a declaration error and I couldn't find another way to implement it.
Giving it a defaultvalue of nullptr, doesn't affect anything.

Full Project is here: https://github.com/Gisbert12843/TextAdventure
Am I suppose to add every single code line of the project here?
The rest of it is completly unrelated to the issue/classes and does work flawlessly.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include "Object.h"
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "Person.h"

class Object;
class Inventory {                                           //High_Level summary of Inventory Items
private:
    string name ="";                                    //Name of the inventory
    std::unordered_map<int, Object *> inventory_map;        //The Inventory based on a hashmap of Pointers to Objects of the 'Object-Class'
    int max_size;                                           //Maximum Size of this inventory
    int current_size = 0;                                       //Current amount of Objects stored in this Inventory
    //Person *owner = nullptr;
    Person *owner;

public:
    
    Inventory(string p_name,int p_max_size, Person *p_owner) { name = p_name, max_size = p_max_size, owner = p_owner; }
    bool addNewItemToInventory(Object* p_addedObject);
    bool removeItemFromInventory(Object* p_removedObject);
    bool hasItem(Object* p_searchedObject);
};
```

---

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "date.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

#include "Object.h"
#include "Inventory.h"

using std::string; using std::vector;



class Person {
private:
    string name;
    char gender;
    date birthdate;
    int age;
    double height;


public:
    Person (string pName, char pGender, double pHeight, string pBirthdate)
    {
        name = pName;
        gender = pGender;
        birthdate = getDateAsDateObj (pBirthdate);
        height = pHeight;
    }

    string getName () { return name; }
    char getGender () { return gender; }
    string getBirthdate () { return getDateAsString (birthdate); }
    double getHeight () { return height; }
    //void takeObject(Object pObjToBeTaken) { ; }

    int getCurrentAge(date pBirthDate, date pCurrentDate = getCurrentDate());
};
```

Comment: what is "a declaration error" ? Please read about [mcve]. The code you posted misses lots of pieces and will lead to lots of compiler errors unrelated to your question. Don't let us guess. Though I guess the issue is mutually including headers

Comment: Looks like a circular include problem, but you seem to know about forward declarations already?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Not enough I would guess, I'll look into it. If you are able to I would really appreciate a quick hint/idea to implement it the right way.

Comment: "Am I suppose to add every single code line of the project here?" surely not. You didn't read the link. [mcve] is enough code to reproduce the error but not more. Most of the code you posted is not relevant for the error.

Comment: @Gisbert12843 adding a link to an external repository doesn't make up a [mcve]. You may want reading that link more thoroughly!

Comment: I did and it really helped thx ^^ but tbh what is the problem with the question then? @Yksisarvinen was able to help me instantly, which answered my question fully

Comment: the problem with the question is that pendantically it is possible to write a `Object.h` such that your code compiles, or produces entierly different errors. And practically, not posting the compiler error message and incomplete code makes it difficult for future readers (ie users that do not know the solution already) to understand if this is the same issue as theirs

Comment: ok i get that thx! will do that in the future

Answer (score 0):

As a commend suggested the solution is called forward declaration, as I actually used before.

You simply predefine the class by adding

```
class Person;
```

over the inventory class.